# Is the monster seen in the Wayne Security commercial a known DC creature?

Tags: dc, character-identification, powerless-tv

[image]

**Reminds me of a giant version of the alien that took over Superman in Batman Beyond JLU episode, but I don't think they are the same.**

Is it a classic dc comics villain?

Comment: The JLU episode alien to which you refer is a Black Mercy http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Mercy while this is definitely Starro

Comment: @jherico not the black mercy, a different creature from his zoo he inherited from the collector. It was in the Batman Beyond series, not JLU

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks suspiciously like [**Starro the Conqueror**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starro), from the first appearance of the Justice League as a team in *The Brave and the Bold* #28 (1960).

[image]

His Wikipedia article also [lists his appearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starro#Television) in *The Powerless*, and [so does ScreenRant](http://screenrant.com/powerless-dc-easter-eggs/).